# While subscribe a user I got eror code 91927 in braintree using node js

Tags: paypal-sandbox, braintree

I'm new to `braintree`. And when I run the `subscribe` user code from node sdk I got this [Error](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all/node#code-91927).

```
gateway.subscription.create({
    paymentMethodNonce: req.body.nonce,
    planId: req.body.planId
}...
```

**Need**

I want to subscribe a user on specific plan in my app.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The payment method must be vaulted before you can associate it with a subscription, so you should refer to the payment method using its [`paymentMethodToken`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create#payment_method_token) instead of a `paymentMethodNonce`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please tell me from where I'll get this token. I think I'll be get token from client side. If I'm right then from where client will get token?

Comment: The `paymentMethodToken` would be retrieved on the server-side when [creating a customer with a payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create#customer-with-a-payment-method)